# Pointer to member function error

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, boost

When I am compiling the following piece of code, I am getting the following error. Can anyone help me in resolving this issue. Thank you.

**error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&foo::abc’ [-fpermissive]**

**boost::thread testThread(boost::bind(&f.abc, f));**

........................................................................^

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

class foo
{
    private:

    public:
    foo(){}

    void abc()
    {
        std::cout << "abc" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;

    boost::thread testThread(&f.abc, f);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message couldn't really be any clearer

> Say ‘&foo::abc’

```
boost::thread testThread(boost::bind(&foo::abc, f));
//                                   ^^^^^^^
```

Also, there's no need for `boost::bind`, this should work too

```
boost::thread testThread(&foo::abc, f);
```

Be aware that both of these make copies of `f`, if you want to avoid that you should use either of the following

```
testThread(&foo::abc, &f);
testThread(&foo::abc, boost::ref(f));
```

---

Now, why on earth is `main()` a member function of `class zoo`??

Comment: Even after removing class zoo, I am getting the same error.

Comment: @shaikh What error? All those options [work for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93c8f533b7c466f5)

Comment: Live its working fine. I do not know why I am getting a long error message.

thread.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `boost::thread::join()'
thread.cpp:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `boost::thread::~thread()'
thread.cpp:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `boost::thread::~thread()'
/tmp/ccAzOPoD.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
thread.cpp:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
thread.cpp:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @shaikh, It's a problem with linker. How do you link boost ? See live's (above) command line: g++-4.9 -std=c++03 -O3 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -pthread -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter main.cpp -pthread -lboost_system -lboost_thread && ./a.out

Answer (score 1):

Do as the error says, replace `f.abc` with `foo::abc`:

```
boost::thread testThread(boost::bind(&foo::abc, f));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
    boost::thread testThread(boost::bind(&foo::abc, f));
```

Comment: Compiler says: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

Comment: Still incorrect, should be &foo::abc

Answer (score 0):

Do as @Praetorian said. Everything works fine:

```
//Title of this code
//Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

class zoo;

class foo
{
    private:

    public:
    foo(){}

    void abc()
    {
        std::cout << "abc" << std::endl;
    }
};

class zoo
{
    public:
    int main()
    {
        foo f;

        boost::thread testThread(boost::bind(&foo::abc, &f));
        testThread.join();
        return 0;
    }
}; 

int main()
{
    zoo{}.main();
}
```

Live: http://rextester.com/XDE37483

Comment: Why two main functions?

Comment: @shaikh, It's your code with a little difference to compile. C++ requires **global** function called `main` [see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function). In your case main() is a member-function of class `zoo`. If you leave it without global, free function main(), c++ will not know how to start program, which function to call firstly